# Why is my code not working in this challenge?

Tags: java, for-loop

The following is a simple code challenge.  The first block is my code.  The second block is the correct code as provided by the challenge author.

Whilst I see how the 'correct' code works, I fail to see how my code does not.  Can anyone shed some light on this ?

```
//MY CODE

public String stringTimes(String str, int n) {

  for(int i=0; i<n; i=i+n){
    str = str + str; 
  }

  return str;
}

//==================================================

//CORRECT CODE

//  String result = "";

//  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
//    result = result + str;  // could use += here
//  }

//  return result;
//}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue occurs is because of the the increment happening in the loop you have used `i+n` which happen to iterate your loop only twice.

You need to print it `n` times so you need to have correct iteration increments.

Also in the code you have used single variable and concatenating the same in each iteration will result in appending the whole modified content of the str varibale. Think about `str` being "A" at the beginning. Then you append it to `"A" + "A"`. After that you have `"AA" + "AA"` and then `"AAAA" + "AAAA"` and so on... 
As you can see, you're doubling the amount of very first `str` on each iteration step(Suggested edit from Tom)

check the code for correct way of doing it

```
public String stringTimes(String str, int n) {
    String result="";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //str = str+str;//(erronous code here)
        result = result +str;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Tom

Comment: @Chris can you mark this as an answer if this solves your issue.

Comment: What is with people down-voting questions on this site ?

Comment: Thank you Vivek for your input.  I now see how and why the forloop was wrong.  It was incrementing by the value of n.

I kind of see how the the concatenation was not quite working.

Comment: Sidenote: It is more efficient to use `StringBuilder#append` than `+` for string concatentation

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { //i starts at 0, as long as i is less than n, add 1 to i.
        str = str + str; //the string becomes itself plus itself.
    }

  return str;
}
```

Comment: Why did you answer the question yourself when the other answer was correct?